# How to use useReducers & react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I'm trying to do some work using the `useReducer` hook and `react-router-dom`. I have 2 pages; 1) Home 2) Details. Using the `react-router-dom` to navigate between 2 components. The details are added to the details page. In the submit action of the `Details` page the `despatch()` is called to save the state.

```
// In Details.js component
const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    name: '',
    age: ''
});
const save_book = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const modified_details = {...details, id: uuidv4()};
    dispatch({ type: 'SAVE', payload: modified_details});
}
```

The `reducer.js` file

```
export const default_state = {
    details: []
}

// Reducer
export const reducer = (state, action) => {

    if(action.type === 'SAVE'){
        const modified_details = [...state.details, action.payload];
        console.log(state);
        return {...state, details: modified_details};
    }

    throw new Error ('HANDLED_ERROR: matching action type found!');
}
```

The details are saved in `state` successfully. But when I try to navigate to the `Home` component the `state` is set to initial.

```
//In Home.js component
const Home = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, default_state);
    // This is a new state variable???

    // This is empty. 
    // {
    //   "details": []
    // }
    return(<> <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre> </>);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share how you configured your redux?
Because, if you're using useReducer the state will be exclusive to the component, except for cases where you're passing it down as props to a child component.

Comment: The state in a `useReducer` hook is local to the component. When the component unmounts it goes away, when the component mounts, it's re-instantiated. Seems you want, or need, to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or some other method of persisting the state such that when you are navigating around your app it persists.

Comment: @JothamArdel thanks for the information regarding 'useReducer'.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the edits and information regarding `useReducer`.